# Why do I get "No space left on device" when running mail

Tags: linux, email, hard-drive, usage

First of all I've checked these [two](https://serverfault.com/questions/93606/why-am-i-getting-write-queue-file-no-space-left-on-device-from-postfix-when-t) [solutions](https://serverfault.com/questions/427091/no-space-left-on-device-but-there-is-space) on serverfault but I'm still having issues.

Here's my problem:

```
root@myserver:/# mail
/tmp: No space left on device
```

- Firstly I checked the filesystem usage by running `df -k` but all filesystem usage was under 25%
- Then I ran `df -i` to check inode usage; maximum was 4% usage
- I have emptied `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` and still get above error

Pertinent information:

- I'm running Debian 6, postfix
- Recently had to remove a number of rogue scripts which were planted in user www directories. They looked like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328235/how-does-this-giant-regex-work these were being used to send high volumes of spam, and I've checked the mail logs and mail queue to ensure spam is no longer being sent. As a result, mail logs had grown very quickly. I have archived the large mail logs to another machine / deleted them, and done the same with all other large files in /var/log

Here's the output of df -h

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda              20G  4.0G   15G  22% /
tmpfs                 249M     0  249M   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                   10M  112K  9.9M   2% /dev
tmpfs                 249M     0  249M   0% /dev/shm
overflow              1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /tmp
```

Comment: Can you paste your `df -h` output in question?

Comment: Yeh - having problems with the mini-markdown in the comment box, newlines not allowed...

Comment: hazymat, edit it into your question instead.

Comment: Your /tmp is 1M big... That's for too small.

Comment: @MadHatter Just trying to edit into the original question but formatting / tabs not lining up - give me a few secs...

Comment: @MadHatter Done :)

Comment: Your `/tmp` has switched to overflow. Do you have a `/etc/init.d/mountoverflowtmp` script? See [the documentation](http://mancoosi.org/~abate/mountoverflowtmp). Do you have sufficient swap?

Answer (score 4):

```
overflow              1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /tmp
```

You have only `1 MB` of tmp space

**EDIT:**

In this way you can increase size of `/tmp`

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/usr/temp-disk bs=2M count=1024
sudo mke2fs -j /usr/temp-disk
sudo mke2fs -j /usr/temp-disk
sudo chmod 1777 /usr/temp-disk
sudo umount /tmp
sudo mount -t ext3 -o rw,noexec,nosuid,loop /usr/temp-disk /tmp
df -h
```

Comment: Thank you. I see your point - 1MB available space is not enough to run mail. How did it get that way? Can a filesystem mount automatically shrink if another requires more space? Sorry for the basic question. It's just that I never changed the available space myself, and mail always used to work.

Comment: See my edit in answer. In that way you can increase `/tmp` space

Comment: Re: FS size; no, filesystem will not get shrink, although there are exceptional cases. In your case, asfaiu, increasing the size of `/tmp` will fix the issue.

Comment: @hazymat: To answer the "how did it get that way" question, see [this page](http://mancoosi.org/~abate/mountoverflowtmp).

Comment: David. Thanks so much for providing that link. Very interesting to learn.

Answer (score 0):

`mail(1)` is not part of postfix.

If postfix has problems sending or receiving mail, this will be logged by the mail.* facility of syslog.

You can check for postfix problems by following the DEBUG_README on www.postfix.org.

Comment: Thanks. I realised now mail is not part of postfix, I was just including the fact I run postfix as an aside. I don't have issues with the MTA itself, just the mail client.

Comment: I'll edit the tags.