# gcloud no space left on device

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, disk-space-utilization, google-app-engine, gcloud

My deployment was not successful with gcloud error log as.

> error building image: error building stage: write /kaniko/888833023:
>   no space left on device Finished Step #1

Do I need to increase space? how can I do it.

On doing df

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev              292268       0    292268   0% /dev
tmpfs              60676    8848     51828  15% /run
/dev/sda1       10253568 2393224   7319880  25% /
tmpfs             303372       0    303372   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             303372       0    303372   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

On doing df -i

```
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            73067   279  72788    1% /dev
tmpfs           75843   821  75022    2% /run
/dev/sda1      655360 53024 602336    9% /
tmpfs           75843     1  75842    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           75843     8  75835    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           75843    15  75828    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No space left on device -- but there is space](https://serverfault.com/questions/427091/no-space-left-on-device-but-there-is-space)

Comment: I did df -i to check inode, it seems to have space left.

Comment: OK, so no duplicate.

Comment: Is there anything i need to check, On building image this happence.

Comment: I have also cleared the Container Registry Images in my gcloud but not working getting same issue.

Comment: Now you have space, but did you have space while you were building your image?

Comment: Yes, I tried deployment, Facing the same issue.

Comment: I've been using GCP (App Engine Flex for Ruby) for half a year and yesterday I stumbled upon exactly the same issue for the first time when running deployment. Maybe this is some GCP issue?

Answer (score 1):

I need to increase the Cloud Build allocating disk volume.

On my app.yaml file I have changed disk_size_gb from 100 to 200 it works now, You can set a max of 1000.

Cloud Platform Support

- https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#options
- https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#buildoptions

Answer (score 0):

Just got the answer from Google Group of Kaniko:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kaniko-users/YtdlbeC79Tw

> Sorry about this! We made a configuration change that seems to have
>   pushed some large builds over the disk size threshold. It should be
>   rolled back now.

Comment: Is that the change done by google, Its not working for me now.

Comment: @fernandus, you'd better ask and describe your issue in that topic in Google Groups. Maybe that would be more helpful